# Is there a better way of writing indexof function?

Tags: haskell

I wrote a indexOf function in haskell. Is there a better way to write it?
My second question is
In my function is the tails function lazily evaluated?

Following is my indexof function

```hs
import Data.List
indexof :: String -> String -> Int
indexof lat patt = helper (tails lat) 0
        where helper [] _  = -1
              helper (x:xs) a = if prefix x patt then a else helper xs (a + 1)

prefix :: String -> String -> Bool
prefix _ [] = True
prefix [] _ = False
prefix (x:xs) (y:ys)  = if x == y then prefix xs ys else False
```

This works as expected.

Comment: I'll leave others to comment on possible improvements to this (I don't find it very easy to understand what's going on at a glance), but it's definitely not very idiomatic in Haskell to return an `Int` and use a `-1` result as a flag to say the string wasn't found, even though this is done in many other languages. In Haskell it's most idiomatic to return a `Maybe Int`, either `Just` (index at which the substring is found) or `Nothing` if it's not found.

Comment: Usually one uses the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm for substring search, since that one has linear time, instead of *m n* time like this one.

Comment: Minor style comment: `if x == y then prefix xs ys else False` is more commonly written as `x == y && prefix xs ys`. Consider renaming `prefix` to `hasPrefix`, to clarify that the second argument is the prefix candidate. Alternatively, name it `isPrefix` and swap the arguments (the standard library does that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks more idiomatic to use the `patt`ern as first parameter, usually failure is not resolved with `-1` or some other value, but by using `Nothing` and thus using `Maybe Int` as return type.

We can use a `foldr` pattern here, which makes it more elegant, and `Data.List` has an [**`isPrefixOf :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf):

```
import Data.List(isPrefixOf, tails)

indexof :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
indexof patt = foldr helper Nothing . tails
    where helper cur rec | isPrefixOf patt cur = Just 0
                         | otherwise = fmap (1+) rec
```

It might however be better to implement the [*Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) since this will result in searching in *O(m + n)* with *m* the length of the pattern and *n* the length of the string. The current approach requires *O(m×n)*.

> My second question is In my function is the `tails` function lazily evaluated?

`tails` is indeed lazily evaluated. The bottleneck is probably not in [**`tails :: [a] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) however, since `tails` runs in *O(n)* on an evaluated list, and requires *O(n)* memory as well, since the `tail` pointers are shared. It thus does not really constructs a new list per item, it simply each time points to the tail of the previous element.

Comment: Thank you for the input would try to implement using KMP algorithm

Comment: Just a little correction. In Big 0 notation , it is just 0(n), no matter if you sum or multiply the n. It is lineal According the number n.

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero The use of big-O notation in this answer looks correct to me. See [big-O notation with multiple variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables).

Comment: @DanielWagner yes but this is not the case, those relationships in the link are exponential

Comment: @DamiánRafaelLattenero So what? If there are multiple variables to consider, it is sensible to describe them all, whether they are linear or exponential or whatever else.

Comment: @DanielWagner but it’s a variation of O notation, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/asymptotic-analysis-for-two-variables, so...

Comment: @DanielWagner I haven’t read this http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~rhowell/asymptotic.pdf about these new proposal of two variables in Big-O notation. After read it clarified a lot to me about the subject. Finally this question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/what-is-the-meaning-of-omn proves I was wrong, and you were right, thanks for the correction and the time. Listen to others and be humble helps to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Building on Willem's answer: usually keeping track of indices is done by zipping with `[0..]`.  The approach here is to find a list `[Maybe Int]` of possible matches, and then take the first one (which is all done lazily, of course, so we never actually compute the list of matches past the first `Just` occurrence).

```
indexOf :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Maybe Int
indexOf needle haystack = firstJust $ zipWith findmatch [0..] (tails haystack)
    where
    findmatch ix suffix
       | needle `isPrefixOf` suffix -> Just ix
       | otherwise -> Nothing

    firstJust :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe a
    firstJust = getFirst . mconcat . map First
       -- N.B. should really use `coerce` instead of `map First`
```

I find this fairly "direct", which I like.  We can cut the code size by being a bit cleverer:

```
indexOf needle haystack = listToMaybe . concat $ zipWith findmatch [0..] (tails haystack)
    where
    findmatch ix suffix = [ ix | needle `isPrefixOf` suffix ]
```

Essentially we are using zero- or one-element lists to simulate `Maybe`, and then using the slightly better library and notational support for lists to our advantage.  This also might fuse well... (I don't have a good intuition for that)

But yes, if you want it to be fast, you should use KMP (on `Text`s instead of `String`s).  It's much more involved, though.